# When is it ok to flatten a database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design

We have designed our database around our business model, with one table per business type. However, since having separate tables for several similar types is causing performance issues, I am considering flattening several related tables into a single table with a discriminator column to identify the actual subtype of each row.

**Issues with our normalized model:**

- Several other core tables have polymorphic references to one of these subtypes that requires a unioned lookup to determine which table contains its referenced object
- Searching and indexing across a union of these subtypes, a common operation, is inefficient
- Semantically identical columns are duplicated across multiple tables

Since we are using Hibernate and JPA, polymorphic joins are difficult and we cannot use views.

**Cons of flattening:**

- Our code is now responsible for the referential type integrity of these subtypes rather than foreign key restrictions setup in the database
- Each row would have null values for irrelevant columns to that type
- Adding a column to any of the subtypes requires adding a column to the whole table
- Columns specific to one subtype cannot be marked non-null

[This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730298/users-asking-for-denormalized-database) recommends keeping a normalized design, but in their situation the subtypes shared only 10 out of 100 total columns. Our flattened table would contain fifteen columns total: eleven shared by every subtype, and the other four shared by multiple types (but not all).

Is this a scenario where flattening makes sense?

Comment: I have a feeling this would fly better at [programmers.se].

Comment: If at all possible I would stick with the normalized version and just try to upgrade the server hosting MySQL. It would probably be cheaper than paying developers to change/test/etc all the code.

Comment: Can you cache to get the performance you require?

Comment: My concern is that while running 10 separate join-heavy queries and unioning the results may be fine for now, and ok for a while after that once we add caching and increase server capacity, at some point it's going to catch up to us. And by that time the problem will be much harder to fix because we built around it, are sharded across systems, customers dont want downtime, etc.

Comment: Usually the need for flattening a database comes due to performance reasons. Where do you need this performance? In searching for information? Then I recommend you create an intermediate flattened database and some mechanism around populating that intermediate database from the normalised database. So that way you keep your referential integrity in the database and don't have to define that in your code model. Your consuming code would use the intermediate database for searching purposes.